# How to assign const enum variable to normal enum variable using C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

I have two enum's like as shown below:

```
typedef enum {
    NONE = 0,
    test1,
    test2
} TestType;

enum class type
{
    zero = 0,
    one,
    two,
    three
};
```

When I am assigning one enum to another like as shown below:

```
const type f_eType;
TestType l_etestType = f_eType;
```

I am getting the below error:

> a value of type "type" cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "TestType"

Could someone please help me how to resolve this error without using `static_cast`.

Comment: `f_eType` and `TestType` are different types.  You have to supply a conversion if you want to convert one to the other.

Comment: "*without using static_cast*" Is there some reason why you put that stipulation in there?

Comment: This is the whole point of scoped enums: to _not_ permit this. Why do you think you need it? There's likely a better way to solve your wider problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use `static_cast` then you'll have to define the conversion behaviour on your own:

```
TestType convert(type val) {
   switch(val) {
   case type::zero:
       return NONE;
   //...
   }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
TestType l_etestType = static_cast<TestType>(f_eType)
```

Comment: The question is literally _"could someone please help me how to resolve this error without using static_cast"_.